# Use IF ELSE statement in Common Table Expression in T-Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

I have a CTE created and I am trying to delete tables using the following. Note that CTE expressions work fine but `IF ELSE` statements does not.

```
IF 
with FinalSales (time, terminal_id, count) as
(
    select time, terminal_id, count(*)
    from Final_Sales
    group by time, terminal_id
    having count(*) = 1             -- condition here
)

delete Sales
from FinalSales
inner join Sales
    on Sales.[time] = FinalSales.[time] 
    and Sales.terminal_id = FinalSales.terminal_id

ELSE IF 

  with FinalSales (time, terminal_id, count) as
  (
    select time, terminal_id, count(*)
    from Final_Sales
    group by time, terminal_id
    having count(*) > 1              -- Condition here
  )
  delete Sales
  from FinalSales
  inner join Sales
      on Sales.[time] = FinalSales.[time] 
      and Sales.terminal_id = FinalSales.terminal_id

   delete #temp1
   from FinalSales
   inner join #temp1
        on #temp1.[time] = FinalSales.[time] 
        and #temp1.terminal_id = FinalSales.terminal_id
```

In the first `IF` statement, when `count(*) = 1` then I delete rows in one table, and then in `ELSEIF` statement when `count > 1` I want to delete rows in two tables. However, my approach does not work.

How can I wrap it into a `IF ELSE` statement? OR is there any other ways to do this?

Whole query in simple structure,

```
if count(*) == 1:
   delete Sales
else if count(*) > 1:
   delete Sales, #temp1
```

something like this. How can I do it in t-sql?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: can't be done in pure Pure SQL as a view.  You'd have to do this in a procedure/package or script.

Comment: @xQbert This statements finally will go into a procedure.

Comment: How many times are you going to ask the same question and not provide the details needed for somebody to answer???

Comment: Which is why you should edit your question instead of spreading details all over the place. If I were a consultant I would be thrilled that you expect to chase all over the place to find your details. But as a free volunteer I just don't have it in me.

Comment: The first cte condition either produces all `count(*) = 1`, meaning no duplicates or it produces a number greater than 1, meaning there is a duplicate so proceed to execute the second statement, correct?

Comment: @Simon correct!

Answer (score 2):

I think this might work:

```
declare @count_of_duplicates int

set @count_of_duplicates = 

(select max(duplicate_count)
from
(       select time, terminal_id, count(*) as duplicate_count
        from Final_Sales
        group by time, terminal_id)  t1)
```

We'll first set the parameter equal to the greatest value of `count(*)`. If there is a duplicate it will be a value greater than 1, else if there is no duplicate it will be 1.

We can then proceed to start our condition:

```
if @count_of_duplicates = 1

begin
with FinalSales (time, terminal_id, count) as
(
    select time, terminal_id, count(*)
    from Final_Sales
    group by time, terminal_id
)

delete Sales
from FinalSales
inner join Sales
    on Sales.[time] = FinalSales.[time] 
    and Sales.terminal_id = FinalSales.terminal_id
end

else if @count_of_duplicates > 1
begin
  with FinalSales (time, terminal_id, count) as
  (
    select time, terminal_id, count(*)
    from Final_Sales
    group by time, terminal_id
  )
  delete Sales
  from FinalSales
  inner join Sales
      on Sales.[time] = FinalSales.[time] 
      and Sales.terminal_id = FinalSales.terminal_id

   delete #temp1
   from FinalSales
   inner join #temp1
        on #temp1.[time] = FinalSales.[time] 
        and #temp1.terminal_id = FinalSales.terminal_id
end
```

I haven't had the chance to parse it... let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Accidentally left the `having` statement in in the `set` part. We don't need it.

Comment: When I run the code I get that `Recursive common table expression 'FinalSales' does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator.` I think it is may be we take `max_duplicatecount` at first.

Comment: No. I see what the issue is. A common table expression may be only called once after it's declaration. The `delete #temp1 from FinalSales` is causing the issue. I'll update it, give me a moment.

Comment: I've updated it, let me know about any other occurs that come up.

Comment: thank you, I found that CTE name should be different. I found it here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164071/top-level-union-error-with-cte. I am used the one that you had before you edited. It works!

Comment: Happy to help. I'll go ahead and edit it one last time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use if exists(query)?

```
IF exists (
    select time, terminal_id 
    from Final_Sales 
    group by time, terminal_id 
    having count(*) = 1
) begin
    --query
end else begin
    --query
end
```